# Code formatting fails for closing brace on some sites

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

The following block of code

````
```

}
```
````

renders correctly when asking a question on most sites, e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and [here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

```
}
```

However, on some sites, like [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), the final triple backticks are shown during preview and also [when rendered](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198332/721190), even as part of a larger block of code:

[image]

Comment: Apparently, adding a line break after the backticks makes them disapear.